# Getting this error .. not sure why? NoMethodError at /mountains undefined method `valid?' for "big":String

Tags: ruby, sinatra, project

```
post '/mountains' do
  @mountain = Mountain.find_or_create_by(
    name: params[:name].strip, 
    content: params[:content].strip, 
    user_id: current_user.id
  )

  if @mountain.save && @mountain.name.valid?
    redirect to "/mountains/#{@mountain.id}"
  else
    redirect to '/mountains/new'
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `valid?` method instance method of `ActiveRecord::Validations`, but I guess you call it on a String. You want to remove the `name` like `@mountain.valid?`

Comment: That was simple. Thank you so much!!

Comment: @Kelly Maass @spickermann 's reply is more accurate, `@mountain.valid?` unnecessary here. `@mountain.save` is just ok. When save fails, it will return false. Rails will invoke the valid method under the hood.

Answer (score 1):

`valid?` is a method provided by [`ActiveRecord::Validations`](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html) and it is called on the record itself, but you call it on the `name` (a `String`) return from `@mountain.name`. Just remove the `name` before calling `valid?`

```
if @mountain.save && @mountain.valid?
```

Furthermore, `save` is calling `valid?` internally before actually trying to save the record into the database. And `save` returns `false` when the record is invalid. That means the `&& @mountain.name.valid?` part in your code is not needed, just remove it completely from the line:

```
if @mountain.save
```